# Adding CR/DR to accounting transactions

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have 7 tables of COA  as show in the picture attached. what I need is whenever opening balance goto - (negative) , the type must automatically show CR sign and whenever that account go to positive, it must change to DR automatically. The account will change to DR or CR as per entries. Suppose I am doing entry in cash payment and if cash in hand account is Debit and utilities are CR in Chart of account, and if I pass an entry then and make utilities debit then in chart of accounts it must change from CR to DR in type column.

Also my accountant do not want to see (-) sign with negative he need type should change as per entries.

Let me explain more. Suppose I have 2 accounts (cash in hand) and (Utility Bills). The opening balance of both accounts in Chart of Accounts is:

- Cash in Hand = 5000 DR
- Utility Bills = 2000 CR

Now if I do an entry in cash payment so it will be

- utility bills (DR) = 8000
- cash in hand (CR) = 8000

Now after I do this entry the Chart of accounts must look like

Cash in hand = 3000 CR (because it is in negative due to I had only 5000) (now here the balance must show like -3000) but instead of (-) it showing 3000 and DR change to CR.

This is what I need to do:

[image: Issue image]

[Error after code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLS6W.jpg)

Comment: You want to make this change while viewing in Gridview right? doesn't matter how it is represented in database??\

Comment: no i want to update in database as well

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should keep the value as it is in database else you need to maintain another column to maintain account status anyway you have CR/DR and I am sure you kept it as boolean.

To convert value to absolute without any sign while displaying you can use below trick. To add CR/DR you have iterate through cells

```
   Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "YourAmountColumnName")) <0 Then
            'Below line will remove (-) sign'
            amt = amt * -1
            e.Row.Cells(n).Text = "CR"
        Else
            e.Row.Cells(n).Text = "DR"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

It will return amount without any sign, If it is less than 0 obviously it is credit else it is debit.

In `MSSQL` you can use case for same, You have to check if amount is going negative

```
Type = CASE WHEN OpeningBalance <0 THEN Type="CR" ELSE Type="DR"
OpeningBalance = CASE WHEN OpeningBalance <0 THEN OpeningBalance= OpeningBalance*-1
```

Comment: how to keep it as boolean ? can u explain more please i am very badly stuck in this situation

Comment: Just ignore about boolean that one we use just to maintain account status. Above snippet checks if value in database is less than 0 then it is CR else it DR.

Comment: vijay your code is for .net ? it giving error of missing amt,(n)

Comment: Yes this snippet I given is to show data in DataGridView, You want it for SQL?

Comment: i want to use it in vb.net and want it to update in ms sql

Comment: Kindly check updated answer, If you think this helps  please mark it as answer and upvote :)

Comment: sounds ok but how i will use it in .net

Comment: See the logic to hide (-) sign is same as above, What issue you have with .net

Comment: issue is how can i write your codes in vb.net including your sql script

Comment: That might be another question? This answer clarifies what you have asked

Comment: check this i use your code and got errors. check attached image with name Error after code